# Solving difference equations

Tags: recurrence-relations

> Given $$\alpha\{v(a + 1) - v(1) \} = \beta v(a)$$
> Deduce $$v(a) = \frac{1-(\beta/\alpha)^m}{1-(\beta/\alpha)} v(1),$$ and derive $$v(a) = \frac{1-(\beta/\alpha)^a}{1-(\beta/\alpha)^{m+n}}.$$

I am new to difference equations, but I am following wiki.

$$v(a+1) = \frac{\beta}{\alpha}v(a) + v(1),$$ which has steady state value $$y^*= \frac{v(1)}{1-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}}.$$

Moving on from here I find the solution to the homogeneous problem as

$$x(a) = \bigg(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\bigg)^av(1).$$

This is not correct. What am I doing wrong? Even if I find the first part I can not see how to progress to the second part ( the derivation part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some information missing regarding $m,n$. But we can make some progress without its knowledge. We start with the recurrence relation
\begin{align*}
\alpha\left(\nu(a+1)-\nu(1)\right)=\beta \nu(a)\qquad\qquad a\geq 1, \alpha,\beta \ne 0
\end{align*}
We can write the recurrence relation as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\nu(a+1)-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\nu(a)=\nu(1)\qquad\qquad a\geq 1}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We use (1) to write down a chain of recurrence equations, each equation multiplied with a factor so that we can apply *telescoping* conveniently. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\nu(a)}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\nu(a-1)&=\nu(1)\\
> \frac{\beta}{\alpha}\,\nu(a-1)-\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^2\nu(a-2)&=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\nu(1)\\
> \left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^2\nu(a-2)-\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^3\nu(a-3)&=\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^2\nu(1)\\
> &\ \ \vdots\\
> \left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^{a-2}\nu(2)\color{blue}{-\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^{a-1}\nu(1)}&=\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^{a-2}\nu(1)\\
> \end{align*}
> Summing up these lines all but the blue marked terms at the left side cancel and we obtain using the *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula)* formula
> \begin{align*}
> \nu(a)-\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^{a-1}\nu(1)&=\nu(1)\sum_{k=0}^{a-2}\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^{k}\\
> \color{blue}{\nu(a)}&=\nu(1)\sum_{k=0}^{a-1}\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^{k}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\nu(1)\frac{1-\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^{a}}{1-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

Setting
$
\nu(1)=\frac{1-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}}{1-\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^{m+n}}
$
we get from (2) OP's final expression
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\nu(a)=\frac{1-\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^{a}}{1-\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^{m+n}}}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Could you have a look over mine to verify it please?

Comment: @HMPtwo: You're welcome. If you want to prove the problem using induction you need to clearly state the base step, induction hypothesis, induction step and show the validity of the induction step.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to invoke difference equations. To obtain $$v(a) = \frac{1-(\beta/\alpha)^a}{1-(\beta/\alpha)} v(1),$$
we just use induction and $$v(a + 1)  = \frac{\beta}{\alpha} v(a) + v(1).$$
Then we use the fact that $v(m+n) = 1$ (This was missing from my original post) to find $v(1)$ as $$\frac{1-\beta /\alpha}{1-(\beta /\alpha)^{m+n}}.$$

Plugging this in the equation for $v(a)$ at the top of this reply and we get the desired result.