# Solving the gamblers ruin problem using induction.

Tags: probability

Using the solution method used in my answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4553064/solving-difference-equations/4553455?noredirect=1#comment9577618_4553455) question. Deal with the case where $\alpha = \beta$.
So we start with the equation $$v(a + 1) =  v(a) + v(1)$$

I'm not sure what I need to prove next. Am I suppose to prove by induction that $$v(a) = c + da,$$
and then use the boundary conditions $v(0) = 0, v(m+n) = 1$ to show that
$$v(a) = \frac{a}{m+n}$$?